# Background color animation jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty much stuck with a functionality that I want to add to a site with the [Color Animation jQuery plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/), what I'm trying to achieve is to switch the color of a certain div every 3s and each time user loads the page this color will be different too, load thing works fine but when it comes to animate it is where I have trouble, heres my code...

```
var colors = ["#00b6ad", "#fdbc5f", "#d91b5c", "#f1592a", "#8dc63f"];                
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length); 
var random_color = colors[rand];          
$('#slider-area').css("background-color", random_color);
setInterval(function(){
   $('#slider-area').animate({backgroundColor: random_color} 500);}
, 3000); ​
```

I thought it could be related to passing variables in animate property because I have no trouble if I put myself a color at backgroundColor I've been googling around but I just can't make it work :S so any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: you are only ever selecting one colour, you need to select a new colour every time your timer runs.  You are currently switching between that one colour everytime, its working but you just cant see it.

Comment: yea that was my bad, even if I change random_color variable at interval nothing will happen

Comment: have you let it run for a little while in case just by off chance its selected the same index twice in a row?

Answer (score 3):

Is the code exactly that?  Because you are selecting a `random_color` once and not selecting a new one in your callback function.

Answer (score 2):

You "just" need the jQuery UI to animate backgrounds:

### *[jsBin demo example](http://jsbin.com/matiqe/3/edit)*

```
var colors = ["#00b6ad", "#fdbc5f", "#d91b5c", "#f1592a", "#8dc63f"]; 

function generateColor(){
    var color = colors[ Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length) ]; 
    $('#slider-area').stop().animate({backgroundColor: color}, 500);
}
generateColor();

setInterval(generateColor, 2000);
```